# Realtime list of viewers in a Google Drive document

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm working on an app which wraps Google Docs (using GAE/Python), and I want to keep track of who is viewing these docs in real-time. I can't find any APIs for this in the Google Drive SDK.

What's a good way to do this? Naively, I might imagine repeatedly polling each document individually and parsing the returned HTML. I expect there to be ~150 docs total in the system; would this be too inefficient?

Answer (score 2):

Realtime api is not for using with gdocs, only for your own custom formats. Instead see the  changes api in drive but you wont be able to detect viewers only modifications https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-changes

Comment: [The Realtime App walkthrough](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/application#step_4_create_or_fetch_a_google_drive_file) claims that
"Realtime documents can also be associated with regular Drive files."

Comment: Yes you can associate it to anything but wont interact with the file, will only be associate your own realtime data to the file, not the gdoc's own realtime data. Try it and when it fails mark this as the actual answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this meets your requirement but there is a [Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/) available in the Drive SDK.

The catch is that it is JavaScript only. It does have Events that your web client can be notified off like [CollaboratorJoinedEvent](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.CollaboratorJoinedEvent) and [CollaboratorLeftEvent](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.CollaboratorLeftEvent).

Comment: Oh sweet, I think `getCollaborators()` at https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.Document is what I need. I should read the API more carefully next time... Thanks!

Comment: Realtime api is for your own custom doc format, not for a native gdoc. On a native gdoc you cannot tell who is viewing, only who is nodifying which you can tell by instslling a hook with the Changes stream.